# Allow tap/press on item while focused on TextInput in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a `TextInput` that functions as a search/filter on some results. The results are displayed in a `ScrollView`.

The issue I have is that while the state is `focus` on the `TextInput`, the user must make two taps in order select the item (which is a `TouchableOpacity`) in the `ScrollView`.

The first tap dismisses the keyboard and `blur`, and the second tap selects the item. This is not the ideal user experience for my particular situation... and I'm not sure if there's a way around it.

Is there a way to make an item selectable while a `TextInput` is in a `focus` state to avoid a two-tap process for selecting an item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the behavior of the `ScrollView` regarding taps and keyboard dismissal via the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` prop of the `ScrollView`.

The most suitable option for the behavior that you are describing is either `always` or `handled`. Both of these options will allow the `ScrollView`'s children to receive the touches without dismissing the keyboard automatically, the difference is that the `handled` option will let the `ScrollView` receive the touch in case it wasn't caught by any other touchable component and dismiss the keyboard in that case.

Comment: What if I am not in a ScrollView? Thanks

Comment: @user2078023 This question is specifically about a case with a `ScrollView`. If there's no `ScrollView` there's nothing that blocks the touches so it's not clear what is the issue in your specific case. I suggest that you create a new SO question with all the details and maybe someone will have the answer

Comment: 1 I have created a new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71513997/react-native-tapping-on-sign-in-button-while-the-focus-is-on-password-text/71537845#71537845

The touches are not blocked, the problem is that the user needs to press the <Button> twice, 1st time the Keyboard hides and 2nd time the Button does what its onPress should. We need to have this in "one-go", pressing the button just once and both the keyboard hides and the onPress being triggered. I do not know how this is feasible when not in ScrollView.