# Click other element when I am focus in TextInput

Tags: react-native, mobile, touch, textinput

When I am inside TextInput with keyboard opened. If I click other component no response, and keyboard dismiss.

How can I make the other element react to my touch if the keyboard is open?

The code:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }} >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => console.log('aaaa')}>    
          <Image source={require('Assets/images/icons/back.png')} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TextInput
          style={[{height: 35, textAlignVertical: 'center', paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, color: 'white'}]}
          placeholder="Music expert, company or music style..."
          onChangeText={this.changeText}
          autoFocus={true}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => console.log('aaaa')}>    
          <Image source={require('Assets/images/icons/close.png')} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
</View>
```

If I am focus in TexInput and I click any ToucableOpacity this just close keyboard, but not show console.log

Comment: please show your code, in the normal situation, it can respond to the click

Comment: @Lenoarod I have edited the post with the code

Comment: hi, I use your code to try, the other component responds to click,
you see the code on the link(https://snack.expo.io/@rns/bold-celery)

Comment: F***k! I have already encountered the problem.

I had the component encapsulated in a scrollview and it was missing to put `keyboardShouldPersistTaps = 'handled'`.

Thank you very much for your help @Lenoarod

Comment: hi have you clear this issue? @Cookie

Comment: my case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812520/allow-tap-press-on-item-while-focused-on-textinput-in-react-native