# React Native: Tapping on "Sign In" button while the focus is on "Password" Text field just hides the keyboard

Tags: react-native, keyboard

(Update: tested in Android only)

I am not in a ScrollView to use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"`.

I tried to just use `Keyboard.dismiss()` in the button's onPress but it has the same behavior (keyboard dismissed without the button's onPress code being triggered).

Is there any other solution?

Thank you!

Sample Code (when the Keyboard is open because of the focus being on the TextInput, and we then press the button, the button's onPress is not triggered because that press is used to just hide the keyboard):

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("Useless Text");
  const [number, onChangeNumber] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
      />
      <Button
        title="Sign in"
        onPress={() => { Alert.alert('Simple Button pressed'); handleSignIn(); }}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default UselessTextInput;
```

Comment: Show snippets of your code; preferably the button and the `onPress`-method.

Comment: I tried your snippet, the problem doesn't reproduce for me. Pressing the button shows the alert right away. After the alert is closed the keyboard appears again because the input is still in focus, but calling `Keyboard.dismiss()` in the onPress handler solves it. Tried it on iOS. Maybe it's an issue with the RN version that you're using, or specific device, OS version etc.

Comment: Thanks Artal, I forgot to mention that I test in Android.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, in scrollview or flatlist pass props keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"

Other option I know is you can directly call the function through keyboard through textinput

```
onSubmitEditing={()=>Your Function()}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not in Scrollview and for `onSubmitEditing` I am not sure if it applies here, since I do not press the "submit" icon. I just press the <Button> which is irrelevant to the TextInput.